# Changing screen resolution in Chrome Remote Dekstop for Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, chrome-remote-desktop

I have setup Chrome Remote Desktop in my ubuntu server using a vnc connection and set the resolution as 1366x 768 however when i connect using chrome remote desktop the screen size is different (appears to be 1366x1366) How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here the solutions...

1)If you want to open the screen at a specific resolution, for example 1280×1024 resolution, add the -g flag:

```
rdesktop -g 1366x 768 [machine]
```

2)if you like using

`rdesktop -g 90% servername`

which will use set the size of the remote desktop to 90% of the size of your local screen, which works quite well regardless of resolution.. :)

Comment: Is this from the server side or client side

Comment: @Shenal Silva its a server side command..try that one

Comment: It says that rdekstop is not installed , reminder I m using chrome remote desktop

Comment: @Shenal Silva code:"sudo apt-get install rdesktop" ,should take care of it.You may also want to install tsclient for a graphical frontend for rdesktop."code:sudo apt-get install tsclient"
You can also use Synaptic Package Manager to do this. Click on System -- Administration -- and choose Synaptic Package Manager.